# P&L explain for swap?

Tags: interest-rate-swap, greeks, gamma, pl-attribution

I try to make a P&L explanation of a swap from the delta, gamma, to the N instruments of the rate curve (money market, futures and swap).
I use a perturbative shock of 1bp for each instrument of my rate curve used in the pricing:

[image]

the result I get is strongly degraded if I integrate the gamma in the P&L explanation (the P&L explain is better with Just delta Effect !) which is counter intuitive

Do you see a mistake in my approach ?

Comment: Is theta left out on purpose?

Comment: For the gamma, you can have an NxN matrix for all pairs of fitting instruments. You're just looking at its diagonal. But it's an overkill for a vanilla IR swap. You can  use one gamma figure for a swap, a risk-weighted sum of the matrix.  If done correctly, it should help your P&L ezplanation a little bit if the swap is 20+ years, not be a lot under 20Y. Can you please post your swaps T&C, all the market data and risk numbers, ideally the QL code that we can run?

Comment: The key observation you make is that the second order term needs to include all the cross gamma terms and not just the individual partial gammas.

Comment: For certain products, it also helps to include the cross-gammas between interest rates and the time.